# Node.js & ejs, how to handle 2 tables?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

Here is a question about `node.js` that I need to answer.
Since I am still a beginner in the field, it may actually be quite easy.

Following some documentation that I found online, I have this code (inside a file called index.js):

```
app.get('/db', function (request, response) {
  pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function(err, client, done) {
    client.query('SELECT * FROM test_table', function(err, result) {
      done();
      if (err)
       { console.error(err); response.send("Error " + err); }
      else { 
        response.render('pages/db', {results: result.rows} ); 
      }
    });
  });
});
```

and I also have this other file called db.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
<h2>Database Results</h2>

<ul>
    <% results.forEach(function(r) { %>
        <li><%= r.id %> - <%= r.name %></li>
    <% }); %>
</ul>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

By some magic between the two I can display the contents of test_table. It works as one would expect.

Now here comes my question:

Along with the query: **'SELECT * FROM test_table'**
I also want to add a second query: **'SELECT * FROM other_test_table'**
and I want to be able to display the contents of other_test_table after (or before) that of test_table.
How do I need to change the code in both places for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
app.get('/db', function (request, response) {
    pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function(err, client, done) {
        client.query('SELECT * FROM test_table', function(err, result1) {
            if (err) {
                done();
                console.error(err);
                response.send("Error: " + err.message);
            } else {
                client.query('SELECT * FROM other_test_table', function(err, result2) {
                    done();
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                        response.send("Error: " + err.message);
                    } else { 
                        response.render('pages/db', {
                            results1: result1.rows,
                            results2: result2.rows
                        }); 
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and in `db.ejs`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
<h2>Database Results</h2>

<ul>
    <% results1.forEach(function(r) { %>
        <li><%= r.id %> - <%= r.name %></li>
    <% }); %>
</ul>

<ul>
    <% results2.forEach(function(r) { %>
        <li><%= r.id %> - <%= r.name %></li>
    <% }); %>
</ul>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yep. That works indeed according to your suggestion, as one would expect.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: After (and while) spending some time dealing with issues like the one in this post. I made my own use case to get some practice with Node.js.
Since other people may be having the same kind of trouble, I thought it might be useful to give access to what I did, hoping it will be useful to someone else at some point. If you are interested take a look here(https://primes-garden.herokuapp.com/). There is a link at the bottom for developers (How That Works?).